# Jquery Mobile: Passing Parameters

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm experimenting with JQuery Mobile by making a basic mobile app, but I've ran into an issue with passing parameters to other pages, be they separate HTML files or additional data-content:pages on the original file.

All I want to do is select a username from a drop down list, press a button, then proceed to the next page, placing the username in the header (e.g. Logged in as: Username). I've looked into multiple solutions, such as sessionStorage, PHP sessions, POST/GET from form submission, and none of them seem to work.

The closest I've got to what I want is submitting the username via POST through a form, then saving it as a PHP session variable, which displays the username on the next page, but when I navigate to another page it once again fails to display.

What is the simplest way to pass a parameter forward? I have a suspicion that it doesn't work on the additional pages due to JQuery Mobile's loading method excluding the session_start() from the header...

Comment: For a single-page app, just keep it in a JavaScript variable. For a multi-page app, either run it via the server or put it into localStorage.

Comment: This should be cleared-up for you. jQuery Mobile has no effect on server-side scripts, like PHP scripts. The PHP will **always** run before outputting data to the browser, hence being called a *server-side* language.

Comment: That being said, I suggest using PHP sessions to store data for users. You will have to poll your server with AJAX to load the data from the server, but other methods are really quite CPU intensive (namely sessionStorage and localStorage, the read/write times are horrible). In a jQuery Mobile website all your pages are added to the same DOM, so you can actually save variables to the DOM (via JS) and access them on the different pages, this will however be erased when the page is refreshed (making PHP session storage more persistant).

Comment: Using JavaScript variables wouldn't be secure however because anyone can alter your JS variables as they want (not so with PHP if you code it properly, in JS there's no way to get around it).

Comment: So your suggestion is to save the variable to the main DOM, using PHP session variable, so that it will be available for all the other DOM's which are injected into it?

Answer (score 1):

I also have problem with php `$_SESSION` in jquerymobile, here i have 4 pages

1. submit form, save in session
2. start session, display correctly, click on link
3. start session, nothing to display, click on link
4. start session, nothing to display

but it ALL WORKS with Internet Explorer 10.

I already did some test with my own program, use `$_COOKIE` instead of `$_SESSION`. Now it runs correctly in every browser with jquerymobile